# How to pass API token with timestamp reliably

Tags: api, security, md5, token

I'm making an API call from one app to another. I handle authorization by passing an `md5`ed shared secret + timestamp...

```
$token = md5( $secret . time() );
```

Then at the API endpoint, I check the authenticity of the request like this...

```
if ( md5($shared_secret . time() ) == $token )
    ...do stuff
```

This works. But it isn't as reliable as I'd like. I suspect the reason is due to latency in the network (or my slow localhost server) causing the timestamps to be mismatched by a second or so.

I worked around this in a lazy way by dropping the last digit of the timestamp, thus creating up to a 10 second window for my slowpoke server to make the call. However, I'm not satisfied with this because if the call happens to fall at the very end of the 9th second, I'll have the same problem again (send at #######49 != received at ########50).

There must be a better way to do this. What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using `token = time || MAC(time, shared_secret)` where || is concatenation and MAC is a Message Authentication Algorithm such as HMAC, that takes a secret key and some data and produces an authentication tag. On the server end, check the MAC is valid and the time (received in plaintext) is within an acceptable window.

This is more secure than your current solution (md5 makes a poor MAC) and also solves your window problem.

Note that this scheme is susceptible to replay attacks within the error window that you allow (e.g. the same token could be sent ten times in a one second window, and the server has no way of telling).

Comment: You're totally right. I forgot about sending the timestamp in plaintext! That's exactly how I did it in the past and I just plain forgot. I'm interested to hear more about what you said about MAC vs. md5. Why is md5 a poor choice? (By the way, I'm working in PHP)

Comment: [Length extension attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack) are a problem for the kind of construction in the question. For example, depending on the format of time, and/or how flexible the recipient is in interpreting time an attacker may be able to use a token to create new tokens for times in the future that would pass validation by the recipient. PHP has an [HMAC implementation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php). HMAC is considered secure when used with md5, but unless you have a particular reason to use md5, I'd suggest sha256.

Comment: That PHP HMAC is great to know about. However, I'm not 100% sure how to apply it in my situation because I'm not sending any encrypted data. Just the shared secret+timestamp. So is this `hmac( 'md5', 'foobar', $secret )` a better token than simply `md5($secret)`? Or maybe they're equivalent and the advantage of `hmac` is the option to use sha256?

Comment: `time || MAC(time, shared_secret)` where MAC is HMAC-MD5 could look like this in php: `$t = time(); $str = $t . ':' . hash_hmac( 'md5', $t, $secret )`. This is indeed a better MAC than `md5($shared_secret . time() )`

Comment: Looks great. Thanks. Just for the my better understanding, what is the difference between the two? Why is the latter better?

Answer (score 0):

Use a nonce instead?  Save the nonce to a DB or some persistent storage to make sure the same one isn't used.

Conversely to your '9th second problem' you have a similar problem for seconds ###...0 to ###...9 hashing to the same value when you cut off the trailing 0 through 9.  It would allow replay in that 10 second time frame.

Seems like that would be more of a problem for guaranteeing/checking authenticity.

You'd have to send the plaintext and hashed text together for the server to check it but that seems a little better than the time stamp method.

Either way, with those two parameters alone you're only checking that it's not a duplicate request as opposed to authenticating anything.

Comment: I'm not really sure what solution you're proposing. However, it seems like you may have misunderstood something: the timestamp is not for authentication. It is used to protect the shared secret. Without it, the call can be easily intercepted and the token compromised. With the timestamp, the API call can be intercepted but that token is useless 1(0) seconds later. Make sense?

Comment: I think I fixated on this: "I check the authenticity of the request like this"

Comment: Did my comment clarify why I include the timestamp?

Comment: Yeah.  You want something with a short lifespan so it can't be used again.  Look at how OAuth protocol works.  It might be a place to start for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using a timestamp is not the correct way because the time is not reliable across systems.  Perhaps you can use the length/hash of the message as a parameter instead.  It does not, unfortunately, prevent playback from an attacker.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems as though you're dealing with authentication (ie, the sender is who they say they are) rather than authorization.  I would suggest that you use SSL/TLS to secure the transmission to know whether or not the transmission is being proxied.

Comment: If the timestamp is not the correct way, what *is* the correct way? I realize that SSL would encrypt the entire call, but that's not really an answer the question I'm asking. For reasons that aren't important here, my system cannot depend on SSL.

Comment: Sorry, edited my post - think in general the timestamp is OK minus for the fact that it is unreliable.